# WordPress Terminology Options Vs. Settings

Tags: plugin-development

What term should be used when defining a page in the admin menu that allows you to change a plugins options?

Comment: While the question regarding the difference in WordPress terminology between *settings* and *options* is valid, asking which term to use for a settings/options page label in the admin menu is primarily *opinion-based*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two are pretty close, but relate to slightly different stages of the process. In purely technical terms WordPress has two different APIs — [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) and [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API).

Options API deals with saving and retrieving options from database. So its scope and scope of "options" in terminology is that of purely *storage*.

Settings API deals with admin pages, forms, receiving/validating/sanitizing data, and finally using Options API to store it. So in terminology it refers more or less to level of admin interface and user interaction.

Depending on nature of your plugin its page should be named either after its own name or after what plugin does. Then it should be nested appropriately in a level such as Settings or Appearance. Creating top level pages for the plugins is not uncommon, but is often considered overblown and annoying, especially so if the plugin/theme doesn't have *many* things to put there.

Comment: The terms _options_ and _settings_ are all too often used interchangeably (and therefore confusingly). This is an excellent explanation of the distinction between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use the name of the plugin. No need to concatenate "options" or "settings" to it.

A lot of times (if the plugin is small, or you rarely need to change it's settings) you place the plugins admin page under the "Settings"-page that already exists.